# PhP file made is not working

Tags: php, html, contacts

This is the **php** file I have made to store the responses from the Contact page of my Html file which is also written at the end.

Even after submitting the data in the contact field I am not getting anything.

Please try to help me out with the error.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields

if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
empty($_POST['email'])      ||
empty($_POST['phone'])      ||
empty($_POST['message'])    ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message

$to = 'abcd@gmail.com'; // This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the
details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";

 $headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; 

$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please use error_reporting(E_ALL) and init_set("display_errors",1) on the top of your file, execute it again, and give us the error message which occours after the script fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **method** and **name** attributes.

You are not specifying the **Form method** . If you want to use post method, you should specify 
`method="post"`.

If you are not specifying the form method, the default method will be **GET**

Also, you should add the attribute name to each and every input fields, then only you can access those in post.

Your updated HTML code will be:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post">
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Look the **method** attribute in form and **name** attribute in input fields.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's still not working. I am not getting anything in my mail. I checked Spam also.

Comment: Please print the output of mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); If it shows 1, then mail has been sent. May be you need to configure your mail settings in your system.